# GSuite - Retrieve groups in organization using non-admin access tokens

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-workspace

I'm building an app that uses GSuite users' tokens to retrieve their events. I currently do not have an admin token, only have the credentials of several users in the organization.

I retrieve the events using the API of [events.list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list). If there's a group invited to that event, I only get that group email as an attendee and not the entire members of this group as attendees.

Is there a way to know (without admin credentials):

1. how many members are included in that group.
2. See the member's emails.
3. Only get the above information about the groups the current user is part of.

*Will the answer to the above question change if those groups are public (within the organization), which means everyone in that GSuite organization can see the members of those groups? 
*I am aware I can use the Admin SDK if I have admin credentials. 
*I want to avoid using a service account. 
*The last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167385/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-all-groups-for-a-member-as-a-non-admin-in-the-google) I found about this was asked in 2015.

Thanks!

Edit: I just learned it's possible to retrieve information about the users in the organization using a non-admin user - https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#retrieve_users_non_admin

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Comment: The main question is - whether a non-admin user can retrieve information about the groups in the domain.
The solution could be either using the Google Calendar API (somehow to tell how many participants include in a meeting) or using the directory API to retrieve information about groups. That's why I divided it like this...